# UILocalNotification not showing up in Notification Center when app is in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I have a `GPS` app that registers to run in the `background`.  I also show a `UILocalNotification` when I have finished a process.  This correctly shows, and if the app is open, then it also appears in `Notification Center` (swipe down from top).  But, if I call the `UILocalNotification` when my app is in the background, or the screen is locked, I DO get the notification, but it does NOT show up in `Notification Center`.

I am correctly registering for notifications in my app delegate (iOS 5 bug workaround):

```
// Register for notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Calling the notification:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.alertBody = msg;
localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View", nil);
localNotif.soundName = @"alert.caf";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];
[localNotif release];
```

Is this a bug? Why would it show up in `Notification Center` only when my app is open, even though the notification is shown to the user, and not other times?

Answer (score 1):

Are you also using push notifications? I believe there is no need to call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` if you are only using local.

Check [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)

Answer (score 0):

*From the look of the code you posted, it does not look like the code would run in the background.  It looks like you are trying to present a Local Notification when an even occurs in the background. You can not do this. Local Notifications are meant to be scheduled while the app is running to go off at a later time when the app is not running, and then they will trigger even when the app is closed.
You need to use Push Notifications. Check out Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) here.*

EDIT: Is your app enabled for the notification center in settings?

Comment: No, the code works perfectly in the background. It has been extensivly tested. The local notification works even in the background, just doesn't show up in notification center.

Comment: Is your app enabled for the notification center in settings?

Comment: Yes it is. It shows in notification center if the app is open.  When in the background it only shows the notification alert.

Comment: Isn't registerForRemoteNotificationTypes only used for Push notifications?  For local notifications I don't think this is needed.

Comment: Yes, but from what I read it was a workaround to add that for a iOS5 bug.

Comment: -1 The first sentence in the documentation you linked contradicts what you said. "Local notifications and push notifications are ways for an application that isn’t running in the foreground to let its users know it has information for them."

Comment: @Chris Wagner: Yes but in order to schedule a local notification you need to have the app running... so you understood wrongly. I will edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @DevinGund I see, yeah I guess I read your response wrong. You are correct you must schedule the notification while it is in the foreground, the notification will be presented even if the app is not in the foreground though. I took off the -1

Answer (score 0):

have you added the UIBackgroundModes key to your Info.plist file ?

You need to have the UIBackgroundModes Key set to location.